# How can I read a string column as a list in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a table. It has two columns `class_id` and `student`. Column student is a list of students. The data type of student column is `varchar`. I want to write a SQL query that returns rows where student columns is a subset of larger list like `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]`

```
class_id      student
1             ["A","B"]
2             ["G","K","E"]
3             ["A","B","I"]
```

For above example, my query should return only one row with `class_id 1`.

Here is what i have so far

```
select * from A where student in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What mysql type is `student` in your `create table`  statement?

Comment: i am not really sure, i didn't create that table.. i think its a string, because i am able to do regex on it.

Comment: Right.  Mysql does not have a native "list" type.  What you have here is not a good database design.  There should be a table with 'id' and 'student' where each row has one id/student relationship.  Thus, your example above would have 8 rows, not 3.

Comment: You will probably have to do this in a program.  I suppose you could look for any record that contains a character not in your alphabet ([]",ABCDEFG), but that's hopeless if your actual data is more than one-character names.

Comment: @TimRoberts in actual they are not id and students, i just used id and students for better understandability, assume students is name of students and id as class id. so class 1 has students a,b. class 2 has students g,k,e. and in actual table they are not alphabets, they are multiple letters

Comment: That's a terrible way to store that data.  You will not be able to do subset operations with SQL.  You will have to write a program, and complain to whoever designed the database.

Comment: Thanks, what format would be better to store a list ? for each primary key that is class_id there would be multiple entry of students... i can ask the DB team to update accordingly

Comment: Which version is your mysql ? or MariaDB

Comment: i am very new to sql. i use normal sql commands to query, should be mysql .. not sure..

Comment: You can get the create table statement by running this query > `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`. Copy the result of that and paste it into your question. Also you can run `SELECT @@version` to find out what MySQL(or MariaDB) version you are using.

Comment: output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`- CREATE TABLE alluxio.realtime_prod_router.doppler ( id bigint, request_id varchar, input_terminals varchar, ....... output of `select@@version` gives me error

Comment: There's suppose to be a space in between `SELECT @@version`. From the create table,  look at the column that correspond to the `student` column in your example above and tell us what us the datatype e.g. `column_name datatype`.

Comment: i did put space. can't edit it now though.. datatype of column corresponding to student is varchar

Comment: I see. Well, it might help with the MySQL version but at least we can confirm that despite the data in `student` looks like a JSON array, the column datatype is not JSON.

Comment: If you put all the "list" in a single cell, either as a string or as `JSON`, you will get a painful lesson of how clumsy SQL is.  Go with Tim's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't repeat the design suggestions above (but please pay attention to them).
We can still process your data as is, given a little effort.  Here's an example using tags instead of names:

Working example:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84641f571cb8e0bd2cb531f5c4ec586d

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE pivot (
   id     int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 , tags   varchar(255)
);
```

The test data:

```
INSERT INTO pivot (tags) VALUES
   ('tag1,tag2,tag3,tag1')
 , ('tag2')
 , ('tag4,tag5,tag4,tag4')
 , ('tag5,tag5,tag4')
 , ('tag5,tag5,tag4')
 , ('tag1,tag3,tag2,tag1')
;
```

Here's a way to normalize the data dynamically:

```
WITH RECURSIVE seq (n) AS (
            SELECT 1
             UNION ALL
            SELECT n + 1 FROM seq WHERE n <= 9
       )
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
     , REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)), ',','') AS tag
  FROM pivot AS t1
  JOIN seq
    ON seq.n > 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)
 ORDER BY id, tag
;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | tags                | tag  |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | tag1,tag2,tag3,tag1 | tag1 |
|  1 | tag1,tag2,tag3,tag1 | tag2 |
|  1 | tag1,tag2,tag3,tag1 | tag3 |
|  2 | tag2                | tag2 |
|  3 | tag4,tag5,tag4,tag4 | tag4 |
|  3 | tag4,tag5,tag4,tag4 | tag5 |
|  4 | tag5,tag5,tag4      | tag4 |
|  4 | tag5,tag5,tag4      | tag5 |
|  5 | tag5,tag5,tag4      | tag4 |
|  5 | tag5,tag5,tag4      | tag5 |
|  6 | tag1,tag3,tag2,tag1 | tag1 |
|  6 | tag1,tag3,tag2,tag1 | tag2 |
|  6 | tag1,tag3,tag2,tag1 | tag3 |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

Given the above normalized list, we can then find if some given set is a subset of a stored set:

```
WITH RECURSIVE seq (n) AS (
            SELECT 1
             UNION ALL
            SELECT n + 1 FROM seq WHERE n <= 9
       )
   , norm AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
                 , REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)), ',','') AS tag
              FROM pivot AS t1
              JOIN seq
                ON seq.n > 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)
     )
SELECT id
     , tags
  FROM norm
 WHERE tag IN ('tag2', 'tag3')
 GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2
 ORDER BY id, tags
;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | tags                |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | tag1,tag2,tag3,tag1 |
|  6 | tag1,tag3,tag2,tag1 |
+----+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.003 sec)
```

Given the above normalized list, we can then find if some given set is a superset (or match) of a stored set (which addresses your specific question):

```
WITH RECURSIVE seq (n) AS (
            SELECT 1
             UNION ALL
            SELECT n + 1 FROM seq WHERE n <= 9
       )
   , norm AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
                 , REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)), ',','') AS tag
              FROM pivot AS t1
              JOIN seq
                ON seq.n > 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)
     )
SELECT id
     , tags
  FROM norm
 GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tag IN ('tag2', 'tag3', 'tag8', 'tag9') THEN tag END) = COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
 ORDER BY id, tags
;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | tags                |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | tag2                |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)
```

With your data:

```
INSERT INTO pivot (tags) VALUES 
    ('A,B')
  , ('G,K,E')
  , ('A,B,I')
;
```

Solution:

```
WITH RECURSIVE seq (n) AS (
            SELECT 1
             UNION ALL
            SELECT n + 1 FROM seq WHERE n <= 9
       )
   , norm AS (
            SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
                 , REPLACE(TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)), ',','') AS tag
              FROM pivot AS t1
              JOIN seq
                ON seq.n > 0 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n-1) <> SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.tags,',',seq.n)
     )
SELECT id
     , tags
  FROM norm
 GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN tag IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G') THEN tag END) = COUNT(DISTINCT tag)
 ORDER BY id, tags
;
```

Result:

```
+----+------+
| id | tags |
+----+------+
|  1 | A,B  |
+----+------+
1 row in set (0.003 sec)
```

Comment: There is no nice way to use your design.  But this comes close, once the data is dynamically transformed into something slightly more usable after the norm common table expression.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question, but it does show how this should have been done.  Write your data as:

```
class    student
 1        A
 1        B
 2        G
 2        K
 2        E
 3        A
 3        B
 3        I
```

Now, you can answer questions like "which classes is A taking?"

```
SELECT UNIQUEROW class FROM A WHERE student='A'
```

and "which classes do A and B have together?"

```
SELECT class, COUNT(*) AS count FROM A WHERE student IN ('A','B') GROUP BY class HAVING count = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achieved if you are using MySQL 8+ / MariabDB 10.6

Using [JSON_TABLE functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

> **JSON_TABLE(expr, path COLUMNS (column_list) [AS] alias)**
>
> Extracts data from a JSON document and **returns it as a relational
> table** having the specified columns.

Lets create a sample table with data

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
 `class_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `student` longtext NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`class_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `table1`(`student`) VALUES ('["A","B"]'), ('["G","K","E"]'), ('["A","B","I"]');
```

To achieve your requirement `select * from A where student in ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")`, we can use JSON_TABLE

```
SELECT DISTINCT(class_id), student
FROM
    table1,
    JSON_TABLE(
        student,
        "$[*]" COLUMNS(
    VALUE TEXT
        PATH "$"
    )
    ) DATA
WHERE DATA
    .Value IN("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
```

**Result will be**

| class_id | student |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["A","B"] |
| 2 | ["G","K","E"] |
| 3 | ["A","B","I"] |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2e44696ab6dccf15b5bcfeaefcde957b)*